# последовательность операции boolean

Tags: javascript

какая будет последовательность операций? 
p == true && !(p && !q) && q != (r || !r && s || !s)

Comment: последовательность: слева направо

Comment: @Grundy не всегда. У операторов есть приоритет и направление. Например, оператор + работает справа налево.

Comment: @MishaSaidov, в данном выражении есть оператор +? и что значит _оператор + работает справа налево_?

Comment: @Grundy нет, но есть логическое отрицание (!), которое справа налево

Comment: @MishaSaidov, логическое отрицание - это **унарная** операции, у нее нет направления.

Comment: @Grundy !!true справа налево

Comment: @MishaSaidov, несколько раз примененная унарная операция остается унарной :-)

Answer (score 0):

Как указано в [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-binary-logical-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) булевские операции **всегда** выполняются слева на право.

В приведенном выражении без скобок 3 операции

1. `p == true`
2. `!(p && !q)`
3. `q != (r || !r && s || !s)`

Именно в таком порядке они и будут выполняться. По такому же принципу будет определяться порядок и внутренних операций.

Answer (score -2):

- p == true && !(p && !q) && q != (r || !r && s || !s)
- ....7.........10..6.....1..0.....9.....8......5.3..........4.2..

[приоритет взял отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

перепроверьте (возможно человеческий фактор))